# Numero de decimales exacto en SQL

Tags: oracle, sql

necesito sacar en una consulta sql un campo numerico en el que siempre se muestren 5 decimales, es decir, que si el numero tiene mas de 5 decimales solo muestre los 5 primeros y si tiene menos de 5 decimales se rellenen con 0 hasta que llegue a los 5 decimales. Creo que se ha entendido pero por si acaso pongo ejemplos:

Si devuelve 1,23 saldria 1,23000
Si devuelve 1 saldria 1,00000
Si devuelve 1,2345678 saldria 1,23456

He probado con la funcion TRUNC() y en caso de que tenga mas de 5 decimales si me lo muestra bien pero si tiene menos no me lo rellena con 0, alguna idea? Gracias!

Solucionado abajo

Comment: ¿Te importaría subir el código que has escrito?

Podrías utilizar TO_NUMBER('1.73', '9.99999')

Comment: Buenas, el codigo es simplemente un SELECT numero FROM tabla WHERE a=b y "numero" es un campo tipo NUMBER(22,5) y voy a probar con lo del to_number

Comment: Me alegra que con TO_CHAR te funcionara, es cuestión de conocer como convertir y los format model. En la documentación de oracle tienes más información al respecto: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm
Te animo a editar tu post para que la pregunta esté mejor estructurada (incluido el título) y pongas la resolución de tu problema mostrando parte del código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solucionado:

Al final he hecho algo parecido a lo que me ha recomendado Ramon, como solo era para mostrar y no para guardar datos he usado to_char(numero,'fm9990.00000') para que me agregue los 0 necesarios o no me muestre mas

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST("yourNumber" AS DECIMAL(22,5))
```

Esto funciona en SqlServer 2012